# Hash Collision in fairly simple encrypt/decrypt code

Tags: hash, encryption

I'm trying to add a small level of security to a site and encode some ids. The id's are already a concat of linked table rows, so storing the encryption in the db isn't very efficient. Therefore I need to encode & decode the string.

I found this great little function from [myphpscripts](http://www.myphpscripts.net/tutorial.php?id=9), and I'm wondering what the chances are of collisions.

I really don't know much about these sorts of things. I'm assuming that the longer my key, the less collisions i'm going to have.

I could end up with more than 10 million unique concatenated ids, and want to be sure I'm not going to run into issues.

```
function encode($string,$key) {
    $key = sha1($key);
    $strLen = strlen($string);
    $keyLen = strlen($key);
    $j=0;
    $hash='';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $strLen; $i++) {
        $ordStr = ord(substr($string,$i,1));
        if ($j == $keyLen) { $j = 0; }
        $ordKey = ord(substr($key,$j,1));
        $j++;
        $hash .= strrev(base_convert(dechex($ordStr + $ordKey),16,36));
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about this issue.

The problem of collisions only applies to mappings that are *not* 1-to-1, but "lossy", i.e. map several different inputs to one ouput (such as hashes).

What you linked to looks like an encryption/decryption routine (if it works correctly, which I didn't check). Encryption by definition means that there is a matching decryption, hence the mapping defined by the encryption *cannot* have collisions (as you could not decrypt in that case).

So your question, as posted, does not make sense.

That said, I would strongly suggest you do not use bandaids like encrypting IDs. Just store the IDs server-side and generate a session key to refer to them.

Comment: @Sleske: I think you are confused. The script uses sha1 function. This is a hashing function not an encryption function. This means it is a one-way hashing & "cannot" be decoded. I say "cannot" as some people say they have reverse engineered the php function. But in principle, a hash is one-way.

Comment: @ForerMedia: the only part that is Sha1'd is the key for salting the encryption. I have tried the encrypt/decrypt, and it does work on the pieces i've tried.

Comment: @pedalpete: I bumped you up a point for teaching me a lesson :)

Comment: @sleske: I see what you mean (kinda) and now that I look at it closer and with a bit more of your insight, I'll have to agree that they will stay unique, but I disagree re:session keys.  This isn't a session based key. It is two strings (keys) put together which I just don't want to pass visibly. As mentioned they are linked through tables and I currently just put the strings together for the request id. But I'd rather not use that so visibly in the URL, so I'm trying to do some simple encryption.

Comment: That was just my point: Don't put anything private into the URL, "encrpyted" or not. Just generate a (random!) session key to put into the  URL, and store the data server-side under the session key. That way the URL does not expose anything, and messing with it gets you nowhere. Standard procedure, really.

Comment: @ForerMedia "Reverse engineered" the function? There's no need to reverse engineer SHA, everyone knows exactly how it works. I think what you meant is they found a way to generate collisions, which is a different story entirely. Truly reversing a hash function is impossible anyways, because hash functions are not injective. And as far as I know the are no known feasible preimage attacks on any SHA variant.